# Spigot Plugin Help (1.20.1)

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

So I'm creating a custom CampfireRecipe to turn rotten flesh into raw beef but it has a probability of dropping a bone instead of beef (30%). Well it does not work.

I think that it does not work because it's not calling getMaterialWithProb() once it has added the recipe to the server, but I'm not sure.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
package es.exmaster.simpletools.recipes;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.NamespacedKey;
import org.bukkit.inventory.CampfireRecipe;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

import es.exmaster.simpletools.Main;

public class RottenFleshCampfireRecipe {
    public static CampfireRecipe get() {
        
        NamespacedKey rottenRecipeKey = new NamespacedKey(Main.plugin, "rotten_campfire_recipe");
        CampfireRecipe rottenRecipe = new CampfireRecipe(
                rottenRecipeKey, 
                new ItemStack(getMaterialWithProb()), 
                Material.ROTTEN_FLESH, 
                0, 200);
        return rottenRecipe;
    }
    
    private static Material getMaterialWithProb() {
        double n = Math.random();
        Material res = null;
        if(n>0.30) {
            res = Material.BEEF;
        } else {
            res = Material.BONE;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Crafting recipes, and consequently, the ItemStack is initialised on server startup; as such, the item is rolled for once and that is then kept until you restart the server.  One alternate solution is to have the recipe result in a template item that can be changed upon craft by listening to [BlockCookEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/block/BlockCookEvent.html).

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @KingsDev Yes, that was the problem, I realised it and I totally forgot about the post lol.